# sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown at "sbt run"

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created a simple Scala console application. I run it by `sbt run` and always receive the following exception on exit:

```
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
[success] Total time: 17 s, completed 30.01.2014 22:19:37
```

After that all my console output becomes invisible. I can type and run applications but I cannot see what I'm typing.

What does this exception means? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of sbt do you use? What's the terminal?

Answer (score 18):

```
// build.sbt
trapExit := false
```

worked for me

Comment: This also has the benefit that "sbt run" exits with the correct status code!

Comment: Since I am building a program that needs to return an exit code, this is the best choice. And since the OP was building a console/shell app, this may also be there best solution.

Comment: If you app is Daemon it doesn't work.. My app just exists few seconds after it starts..

Answer (score 12):

You can fork your JVM when running a console application within an SBT session. That way when your console application exits it won't kill the hosting sbt JVM. I'm doing this for `main` classes in my integration test configuration.

In `build.sbt` (or your equivalent sbt project configuration file):

```
fork in (IntegrationTest, run) := true
```

(you may want simply `fork in run := true` to cover a console main). Then in any class that extends `App`:

```
package com.example

object StuffMain extends App {
  println("stuff")

  sys.exit(0) // 0 is a successful Unix exit code
}
```

(You may not need a `sys.exit` call at all, if your application doesn't keep the forked JVM alive.)

In my case I can then execute this integration test `StuffMain` by running:

```
sbt> it:runMain com.example.StuffMain
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what SBT version you use, but with SBT **0.13.2-M1** it was quite easily reproduced with the following class:

**Hello.scala**

```
object ExitApp extends App {
  exit(0)
}
```

The class exactly shows when the exception `sbt.TrapExitSecurityException` gets thrown - whenever the method [java.lang.Runtime.exit(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29) is called.

```
$ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/TrapExitSecurityException/project
[info] Set current project to trapexitsecurityexception (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/TrapExitSecurityException/)
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Running ExitApp

Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Jan 30, 2014 9:05:24 PM
```

Remove the call from your application and the exception goes away. According to `sbt.TrapExit` scaladoc:

> This category of code should only be called by forking a new JVM.

Why do you use it at all?

Comment: my sbt version is 13.0. error occurs when i do `sys.exit(0)`. what is the correct way to terminate the program?

Comment: Just let it finish without `sys.exit(0)`. If an application doesn't have non-deamon threads and the main thread terminates, so will the application.

Comment: sys.exit would kill the jvm on wich sbt runs on. Sbt implement a security manager to avoid this. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running-Project-Code.html#System.exit

Comment: The correct way to terminate is just to let the main thread return.

Additionally, this looks like a bug with Jline "reset terminal".  Please open an issue on sbt, as you should get the console back.  Our security manager is designed to allow sys.exit(0) in code and not die horribly.

Comment: There are many situations where you want to exit a console application with something else than 0, like `System.exit(1)`. It's obvious why.

Comment: I need to return the error/exit code to enable other processes to observe and react to the termination of this process. I am building a progress library that records the error code, so that processes can persist their progress/exit codes. But I need a mode for the assembly to check and emit the code to the shell via exit(code).

Answer (score 6):

This exception is not a bug.

SBT is simply warning you that the running application called `sys.exit(0)`. Instead of terminate the JVM (and killing SBT on the same occasion), SBT intercepts that call and keep the JVM running, so you can continue to interact with SBT.

I found this explanation by inspecting the source code of SBT:

```scala
/** SecurityManager hook to trap calls to `System.exit` to avoid shutting down the whole JVM.*/
  override def checkExit(status: Int): Unit = if (active) {
    val t = currentThread
    val stack = t.getStackTrace
    if (stack == null || stack.exists(isRealExit)) {
      exitApp(t, status)
      throw new TrapExitSecurityException(status)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what the OP had but I ran into the same error message and wanted to share my solution for others to find. I'm using Guice for dependency injection and had found myself in a circular dependency situation. This was causing my application to barf when it was trying to set everything up and create all my singletons to inject.

A little more in case that wasn't clear enough.

- SingletonA injects SingletonB
- SingletonB injects SingletonC
- SingletonC injects SingletonA  <-- barf because SingletonA hasn't finished being instantiated yet.

I hope that helps someone find a solution quicker. My circle had 3 singletons involved, as illustrated above, so it took me longer to realize.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when the port was already occupied. Launching the application on a different port solved the problem.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI7hS.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).