# sbt.TrapExitSecurityException error message in from Chisel (rocket-chip)

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip

I have gotten this fascinating exception (no additional backtrace, that's it) in rocket-chip Chisel elaboration.

```
[info] [0.003] Elaborating design...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception thrown when elaborating ChiselGeneratorAnnotation
Try --help for more information.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
```

This is from PR https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/pull/2310. I have managed to hose the generator so completely with so little information in a way I've never seen before. Anyone know what this sort of error means?

Comment: Is there any more info below the last line? From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464673/sbt-trapexitsecurityexception-thrown-at-sbt-run this can be caused by a few things, like calling `sys.exit(...)` or circular dependencies in inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to a recent PR to add Staged Compile: https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/pull/2274/files