# Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-1" Lila Lichess

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to use Lichess' open source and everything is setup, except for when I finally run I get this error

```
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-1"
```

Comment: Does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390137/2123530?

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464673/sbt-trapexitsecurityexception-thrown-at-sbt-run) your quetion

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I did to resolve this issue:

1. Set up websockets in a different terminal tab:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ornicar/lila-ws.git
   cd lila-ws
   sbt run
   ```
2. Also in a different terminal tab, make sure MongoDB is running:

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```
3. Build the UI:

   ```
   ./ui/build
   ```

Once I ensured MongoDB and the websockets were running, `./lila` followed by `run` worked just fine!